# Apache + mutli php version

Tags: php, apache

Apache 2.4.25 + php 5.6.30 + php 7.1.4
I did this successful, several times. But now php 5.6.30 cannot work, only php 7.1.4 works.
Too strange...

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
ScriptAlias /php-5.6.30/ "D:/Codes/webserver/php/php-5.6.30-Win32-VC11-x64/"
ScriptAlias /php-7.1.4/ "D:/Codes/webserver/php/php-7.1.4-Win32-VC14-x64/"

<Directory "D:\Codes\webserver\php">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Codes\wwwroot\tests\php71"
    ServerName php71.local
    ErrorLog "logs/php71-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/php71-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\Codes\wwwroot\tests\php71">
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php-7.1.4/php-cgi.exe"
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Codes\wwwroot\tests\php56"
    ServerName php56.local
    ErrorLog "logs/php56-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/php56-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\Codes\wwwroot\tests\php56">
        Action application/x-httpd-php "/php-5.6.30/php-cgi.exe"
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Both index.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I did this on my pc, ok.
Then I did this on my nb, ok.
I re-install nb's windows 10, ok.
Now I re-install pc's windows 10, not ok.

The page shows 500 Internal Server Error.
error log of php56 is:
End of script output before headers: php-cgi.exe

How to fix this?

I added everyone permission on php56 folder, not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Install:
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4